# How to set string value to wpf image source?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set hex string The following format that start with `0x` to source of `<Image>` control. Data in resource is :

```
var myImageData = "0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D0F910000000467414D410....."
```

I used the following method to convert to byte array myImageData :

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string data)
{
     var bytes = new byte[data.Length * sizeof(char)];
     System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     return bytes;
}
```

And use the following method to create image source :

```
private static BitmapImage LoadImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        mem.Position = 0;
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.UriSource = null;
        image.StreamSource = mem;
        image.EndInit();
    }
    image.Freeze();
    return image;
}
```

In load window :

```
var imageDataBytes = GetBytes(myImageData);
MyImage.Source = LoadImage(imageDataBytes);
```

But has error in line `image.EndInit();`

> `No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.# InnerException : The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)`

Comment: You should be using base-64 encoding for your image (its much smaller than 2 digit hex, but what this boils down to is needing a custom converter. See http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: @Ron, i also tried this method, but i like a failure in Line `image.EndInit()`.

Comment: @RonBeyer my Data already created by format shown above in DB ,i can not convert to other formats. 
string data format is : "0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D0F910000000467414D410....." that start with `"0x.."`

Comment: Its because you are creating a memory stream from the *character* values, not the actual bytes. You need to convert the hex string into a byte array first, then use it in the memory stream. Since I assume your hex string is arbitrarily long, I don't think there is a built-in utility to do it, you'll need to write one.

Comment: @RonBeyer,Yes, of course,thanks for your help,this i did and i got the answer,I tried this method before, but I did not answer.ok,tanks

Comment: @RonBeyer,only exist one problem,only load small part of image!!
how to resolve it.